# How to add different colors in shape in Sketch 3.4? Is there selective fill possible?

Tags: color, sketch-app, fill

[image: ****]

Here is the screenshot of what i want to do. Also if there is some other method please tell!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create two rectangles with red and blue fills.

1. Create red rect and select Edit mode, then add points in bottom as shown below:

[image]

2. Add blue rect under the red one:

[image]

3. You can group two rects for further usage (dragging, resizing):

[image]